# How can I get taskbar buttons for forms that aren't the main form?

Tags: windows, delphi, forms

How do you make a form appear on the taskbar in Delphi? In Firefox, for example, when you open a page in a new window, it creates another window on the taskbar without creating a new process. At the moment my Delphi application opens a new form when a button is clicked, but there is still only one thing on the task bar, so you can't alt-tab between the main form and the form that is created when the button is clicked. How do I change it so that the new form appears with a new taskbar button? My current code looks like this:

```
procedure Form1ButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
    Form2.Show;
end;
```

I have been messing around with `CreateWindowEx`, but ideally I would like to find a simpler solution than directly using the Windows API.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If I understand what you want correctly, you can show your secondary forms on the task bar by overriding it's CreateParams procedure, as explained in [Minimize child forms independent of the main form](https://web.archive.org/web/20170326021529/http://delphi.about.com:80/od/formsdialogs/a/child_forms.htm) delphi.about.com article, like this:

```
interface

type
  TMyForm = class(TForm)
  ...
  protected
    procedure CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams) ; override;
  ...

implementation

procedure TMyForm.CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams) ;
begin
  inherited;
  Params.ExStyle := Params.ExStyle or WS_EX_APPWINDOW;
  Params.WndParent := 0;
end;
```

Comment: The About.com article is wrong regarding how to set WndParent. The Old New Thing explains why [it's wrong to make the desktop be the parent of your application's windows](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/02/24/79212.aspx). I've fixed the code here.

Comment: You should do one or other, but no need for both in CreateParams.

Answer (score 1):

if not using of this line is better in form order :

```
Params.WndParent := 0;
```