# SDI application with multiple instances shown on taskbar

Tags: delphi, vcl, delphi-10.1-berlin

I've created an SDI application using the Delphi Berlin VCL template. I can create additional instances by programming File|New as follows:

```
procedure TSDIAppForm.FileNew1Execute(Sender: TObject);
var
   LNewDoc: TSDIAppForm;
begin
   LNewDoc := TSDIAppForm.Create(Application);
   LNewDoc.Show;
end;
```

Only the owner form shows on the taskbar. Also, closing the owner form closes all the instances. How do I unlink the additional instances so that they operate independently and show individually on the taskbar?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get taskbar buttons for forms that aren't the main form?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493591/how-can-i-get-taskbar-buttons-for-forms-that-arent-the-main-form)

Comment: Not entirely a duplicate because I was also asking about how to get multiple SDIAppForms that operate independently.

Comment: Duplicate of [Delphi, how to make independent windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2618372/delphi-how-to-make-independent-windows/2619792#2619792)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Closing the `TForm` that is assigned as the `Application.MainForm` exits the app, that is by design.

If you want the `MainForm` to act like any other SDI window and be closed independently without exiting the app if other SDI windows are still open, you will have to create a separate `TForm` to act as the real `MainForm` and then hide it from the user (set `Application.ShowMainForm` to false at startup before `Application.Run()` is called), and then you can create `TSDIAppForm` objects as needed.  When the last `TSDIAppForm` object is closed, you can then close the `MainForm`, or call `Application.Terminate()` directly, to exit the app.

To give each `TSDIAppForm` its own Taskbar button, you need to override the virtual `CreateParams()` method:

[How can I get taskbar buttons for forms that aren't the main form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493591/)

Try this:

```
begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
  Application.CreateForm(TMyRealMainForm, MyRealMainForm);
  Application.CreateForm(TSDIAppForm, SDIAppForm);
  SDIAppForm.Visible := True;
  Application.ShowMainForm := False;
  Application.Run;
end.
```

```
procedure TSDIAppForm.CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams);
begin
  inherited;
  Params.ExStyle := Params.ExStyle or WS_EX_APPWINDOW;
  Params.WndParent := 0;
end;

procedure TSDIAppForm.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  Action := caFree;
end;

procedure TSDIAppForm.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Screen.FormCount = 2 then // only this Form and the MainForm
    Application.Terminate;
end;

procedure TSDIAppForm.FileNew1Execute(Sender: TObject);
var
  LNewDoc: TSDIAppForm;
begin
  LNewDoc := TSDIAppForm.Create(Application);
  LNewDoc.Show;
end;
```

Comment: Developing my SDI program a bit further, I added a TAdvStringGrid from TMS Software and saw that this resulted in the creation of two additional forms. So terminating the application when Screen.FormCount reduced to 2 no longer worked. I therefore modified FormDestroy as follows:

`procedure TSDIAppForm.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: Integer;
  NumAppSDIForms: Integer;
begin
NumAppSDIForms := 0;
  for I := 0 to Screen.FormCount - 1 do
    if Screen.Forms[I].UnitName = 'SDIMAIN' then
      Inc(NumAppSDIForms);
  if NumAppSDIForms = 1 then
    Application.Terminate;
end;`

Comment: @Duns you have the right jist. I would use `if Screen.Forms[i] is TSDIAppForm then`, though.